# how to know if a radio button is checked or not in controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using radio buttons and I want to know if they are checked or not in the controller. Is there any other way to find that out in angular except  (  document.getElementById( "radio_button" ).checked ) ?

Comment: Please post your checkbox html code.

Comment: Use `ng-model`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: Note: checkbox and radio are different. Please make sure which one you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can trigger the function on click like this :

In HTML :

```
  <div  ng-click='newValue(value)'>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="firstValue">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="secondValue" > </div>
```

You can also observe the model change by using ng-change as follows :

In Javascript :

```
        $scope.newValue = function (value) {
                    alert(value);
                }
```

You can even watch the value by using $watch like this :

```
            $scope.$watch('value', function(value) {
                   alert(value);
             });
```

However, using ng-change is better and efficient than $watch and is easier to test.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

You can do it in more simpler way.

```
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">

   <label>Check me to check both: 
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master" ng-checked="checkTest(master)"></label><br/>

  </body>
```

JS :

```
 $scope.checkTest = function(boolChecked){

      console.log(boolChecked)
    }
```

Here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UiKJSKK2c1HGZBZG5gqw?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a few different ways:

**with Radio Buttons**

In your HTML

`<input type="radio" ng-value="isButtonChecked">`

In your controller

`$scope.isButtonChecked  = true;`

**with another element tag**

In your HTML

`<div ng-click="isButtonChecked = !isButtonChecked"></div>`

In your controller

`$scope.isButtonChecked  = true;`